# Should questions like "Did [scripture] predict [event]?" be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Consider the following question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/291/13. It is possible that many other questions like this could be asked. For example, I could ask "Did the Mahabharata prefigure the Moon landings?" or "Does the Ramayana foretell the birth of Hitler?".

Should questions like these be on-topic?

Answer (score 5):

I think that these questions should be closed **with extreme prejudice** as "primarily opinion-based". These questions are bound to attract uninformed opinions from users who have no business attempting to extricate prophecies from scripture. We cannot allow questions like this on the site. It will destroy the site.

It may be possible to salvage some of these questions by making them about the interpretations of other religious scholars. For example, I would be okay with a question like "What did [scholar X] say about the Puranas prophesying the partition of 1947?", because these are objectively answerable and will not attract many worthless opinions.

---

Here are some short chat conversations I had with the moderators of Christianity.SE on this topic: [Questions about prophecies (1)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/conversation/questions-about-prophecies-1) and [Questions about prophecies (2)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/conversation/questions-about-prophecies-2).